# Checking constructor arguments for a generic type at compile time

Tags: c#, parameters, compilation

I'm writing a state machine handler, and I have the following change state function that simply forwards any argument I pass it to the given type's constructor.

```cs
public void ChangeState<T>(params object[] constructorArguments) where T : IState
{
    IState newState = (IState)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), constructorArguments);
    UpdateState(newState);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way for me to ensure - at compile time -  constructorArguments are valid for any T constructors.

Comment: If you want compile time safety, why not just use `UpdateState(new MyState(...))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Roslyn analyzer that looks for this invocation, determines the `T` (if it is concrete, rather than forwarded as a generic from some other code-path), resolve the constructors of `T`, check the parameters, and compare that to the declared types of the supplied values (assuming they aren't all just `object`). So in essence, "yes". It isn't trivial, and requires learning Roslyn - but: it is possible.

However, I wonder whether an alternative design here might be more practical; for example:

- have the caller create the `T` and just pass it in fully constructed
- a `Func<T>` callback without parameters (using "capture" at the supplier for the arguments); you just invoke it
- a `Func<TState, T>` callback, along with a `TState` parameter (commonly used with value-tuples for the `TState`), i.e. `args => new Foo(args.X, args.Y)` passing `(X: 42, Y: -4)` as the `TState` parameter

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion makes total sense, I really don't know why I wanted to get so complicated... Also I was trying to pass in an Action delegate which wasn't possible as Action is not an "object", so thanks for catching two birds with one stone :)